# Attept to reduce partition size using Logical Volume Managment ran into problems

Tags: partitioning, lvm

I attempted to reduce the size of my root logical volume in my dev/sda3 partition by 1GB using the LVM gui to make more room to increase the size of a too-small boot partition.  Now I cant boot and can't recover the data on the root partition. Here's  a couple of diagnostics below:  If anyone can help me get back to where the data in the root partition is gettable I'd appreciate it.

PVS gives

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:/$ sudo pvs --segments /dev/sda3
  PV         VG        Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree Start  SSize 
/dev/sda3  ubuntu-vg lvm2 a--  930.53g 1.00g      0 235939
/dev/sda3  ubuntu-vg lvm2 a--  930.53g 1.00g 235939    257
/dev/sda3  ubuntu-vg lvm2 a--  930.53g 1.00g 236196   2020
```

e2fsk gives me

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:/$ sudo e2fsck -f dev/sda3
e2fsck 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
ext2fs_open2: Bad magic number in super-block
e2fsck: Superblock invalid, trying backup blocks...
e2fsck: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open dev/sda3

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
or e2fsck -b 32768 <device>
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: The filesystem will be "on" a LV not the PV - you will need to drill down from PV --> VG --> LV (using `vgs`, `lvs` and/or `lvdisplay`) - or look for the volume under `/dev/mapper`